# CVS Update Equivalent in Git

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout

I am new to git.So please forgive for basic question.
I have couple of checkouts of repos: `Folder1` is on `Server1` and `Folder2` is on `Server2`.

`Folder2` only "`git pull`" changes.
This fetches all files which is checked-in from Folder1.

I want to update only specific file something like "cvs update filename"

```
cvs update filename
```

I tried "`git checkout -- filename`" which simply not doing anything.
I followed these step:s

```
#Commit and push changes in foo.txt from Folder1 on Server1.
# On Servers 
cd Folder2
git checkout -- foo.txt
```

Above command is just not doing any updates.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have 2 similar repos on different servers why do you expect pushing to Server1 would cause the repo on Server2 to be updated as well?

Comment: I have only one repos which is checked out in two different folders.One on server1 and other on server2.When I check-in from folder1 , run git pull on folder2 then it updates all files.I just want to pull selected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have push a commit from repo1 to repo2, then repo2 should directly see the updated file.
But just in case, You need to:

```
git fetch repo1
git checkout repo1/master -- path/to/file
```

Provided that `repo2` has a remote named "`repo1`".
If that remote is named "`origin`" (default name), then

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
```

In both cases, to see update on a specific file from a remote repo (like `repo1`), you need to fetch that remote repo first into `repo2`.

Comment: I completely mis-formed my question.I have updated my question.That will elaborate exactly What I am looking for.Thanks for your Answer

Comment: @MANISHZOPE that shouldn't change my answer: each of your Folder are a git repo. Call them `Repo1` or `Folder1`. `git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file` should still does what you want.